# UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior

Tags: c++, palindrome

I am trying to solve palindrome number problem using object oriented cpp. I faced an occurrence of an strange error in my code which say "signed integer overflow: -1734809184 * 10 cannot be represented in type 'int'". Here is my code and  I require some useful assistance to pass the test cases.

```cpp
class Solutiuon {
public:
    bool isPalindrome(int x) {
        int rev, temp;
        temp = x;
        while (x > 0) {
            rev = rev * 10 + (x % 10);
            x /= 10;
        }
        if(rev == temp)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
};
```

With my code I am expecting it to return true for palindrome number and false for non-palindrome number.

Answer (score 3):

You are experiencing classic undefined behavior. In your code, the variable `rev` is uninitialized before you access is it in `rev = rev * 10 + (x % 10)`.

You should start off by initializing `rev` to `0` *explicitly*. C++ is not doing this for you automatically. Without explicitly initializing it, the value could be *anything*.

As an additional note, there is nothing object-oriented about your solution.

And as a last note:

```
        if(rev == temp)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
```

Is equivalent to:

```
        return rev == temp;
```